# VBA copying range to new workbook.Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: vba

There have been many questions similar to this and I have tried the different solutions provided from copying ranges, cells variants but I still end up having the same run time error. Object doesnt support this property or method. Where am I going wrong?

```
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim vals As Variant

    Set wkbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    Set myRange = Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Address)
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(filename:="C:\Users\Diarmuid.Campion\Desktop\newFile.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

    vals = wkbSource.wsJournals.myRange.Value 'causing error
    wbDest.ws2.Range("a1").Value = vals

    'wsJournals.myRange.Copy
    'ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim vals As Variant

    Set wkbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    Set myRange = Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Address)
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(filename:="C:\Users\Diarmuid.Campion\Desktop\newFile.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

    vals = wkbSource.wsJournals.myRange.Value 'causing error
    wbDest.ws2.Range("a1").Value = vals

    'wsJournals.myRange.Copy
    'ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=
```